# Buildozer to android Signing Issues

Tags: android, compilation, kivy, buildozer

Ok...  Things have changed.  I think I can get it to work but I ran into a new problem.  I get an error stating that I'm out of space on the VM drive.  (GOD!!!)

I tried doing the compile using the shared folder but permission errors kill the process doing that.

IDK what to do at this point.  The .buildozer folder is not even 200mb in size so how can the VM drive be out of space?

------Solved First Part-------------------
I solved the first issue.  Buildozer's vdi download should not be used.  The vdi size is only 8gb and that's not big enough for compiling projects.  I instead create a new larger vdi, downloaded Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and installed to the virtual machine.

Linux had it's issues and I ended up fixing up the system...one issue being the window didn't auto resize after guess auditions installed.  Anyway, I just installed buildozer anew, along with the dependencies, cython 0.21 etc and re-ran the build process.

Now, the apk created doesn't install on my android.  There's no error message except, "apt not installed."  Anyone know what the deal could be?

-----update

I can't finish the signing of my apk because I don't have an sdk folder with sdk tools in .buildozer.  Any one know why?  I need zipalign from the tools

Comment: open your buildozer spec file and set `log_level = 2`. then run buildozer debug again and edit the question providing more verbosity

Answer (score 0):

I found out a lot about the linux system since I posted this topic.  As a windows user, I'm not familiar with the way linux unbuntu can hide things.  Anyway, the buildozer path was a hidden path that started with a dot.

Once I was able to located everything, I had no problems signing my apk.  I'm finding out though that kivy is very light weight.  Not sure if I'll continue using it.